# What are the appropriate file security settings and Apache settings for Drupal sites running on a VPS?

Tags: files, security

I would be grateful for some help on this one - I have looked at the other posts on this subject with interest, but they don't seem quite to fit my situation. I'm not a great Unix expert, but there are some aspects of my Managed VPS provider's setup which seem strange to me.
Looking at the Apache process (ps -ef | grep httpd) I can see 6 processes running under user 'nobody', but also two processes running under 'root'. This does not seem normal to me, although when I asked the hosting provider about this, their support said it was necessary to run APC. But is this true?

The other thing I don't understand, which may be linked, is that the server seems to create files under my VPS user name (say, 'joe') instead of 'nobody' which is what I would expect. For example, when I run the "security_review" module, it creates IGNOREME.txt owned by 'joe' and group 'joe'.

I can't help thinking that this means that anybody who could somehow download a script to my server could then wipe all the files on it, since the file would be created under 'joe' instead of 'nobody'.

I would also be very glad to have a script to put correct file permissions which does not need to be run by the user 'root'.

Comment: Are you running PHP as mod_php or as CGI?

Comment: It's running as mod_php